# Modifying the output using AWK

Tags: awk

Having a data set like below shown with (:)colon delimeted:

```
##L1
Advc:start:TA_Wk;TA_Wk:rstb:ver:trstb.techind_C3_D[0].RESETH:LK

##L2
ner:ted:Unused:C1500:ver:sync3rmsfd0nt_t;tape_out:SOCK0
```

I am using the column number's and I am attaching some strings to it using AWK.
And I am trying to ignore the COmments which encounter's with # and appending them at last.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F: '/^#/ {c=$0; sub(/#+/,"", c); next}
{print $1, "-f" " "$4, "-t" " "$6, "-d" " ""{"$3"}", "-t" " ""{"$7"}","-", "\"" c "\""}' s1
```

Output:

```
Advc -f rstb -t trstb.techind_C3_D[0].RESETH -d {TA_Wk;TA_Wk} -t {LK} - "L1"
 -f  -t  -c {} -c {} - "L1"
ner -f C1500 -t sync3rmsfd0nt_t;tape_out -d {Unused} -t {SOCK0} - "L2"
```

Desired Output:

```
Advc -f rstb -t trstb.techind_C3_D[0].RESETH -d {TA_Wk;TA_Wk} -t {LK} - "L1"
ner -f C1500 -t sync3rmsfd0nt_t;tape_out -d {Unused} -t {SOCK0} - "L2"
```

1.In column 3 and column 7 if words like are "Unused", "Unspecified" then it should not print that particular column it should ignore along with the string attached to it as shown above in desired output.

2.HOw to remove empty lines.

How to fix above two conditions in my code as shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***OP's attempt fix:*** Fixed OP's attempt itself here. You need to skip empty lines to print your output correctly which you could do with simple if condition + I did minor changes in your attempt like changing `sub` to `gsub` in removing `#` part, setting `:` within `BEGIN` section + give variables well defined name so in place of `c` I changed it to `val` for better understanding.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} /^$/{next} /^#/ {val=$0; gsub(/#/,"", val); next}
{print $1, "-f" " "$4, "-t" " "$6, \
($3!="Unused"?"-d" " ""{"$3"}":""),\
 ($7!="Unspecified"?"-t" " ""{"$7"}":""),"-", "\"" val "\""
}' s1="\""  Input_file
```

---

---

***My attempt to solve this:*** Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
 FS=":"
}
/^$/{
  next
}
/^#/{
  val=$0
  gsub(/#/,"", val)
  next
}
{
  ($3=$3!="Unused"?"-d" " ""{"$3"}":"")
  ($7=$7!="Unspecified"?"-t" " ""{"$7"}":"")
  print $1, "-f" " "$4, "-t" " "$6, \
  $3,\
  $7,"-", "\"" val "\""
}' s1="\""  Input_file
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216116/discussion-on-answer-by-ravindersingh13-modifying-the-output-using-awk).